# "Locking" a node after a certain period of time

Tags: 7, nodes, users, workflows

I'd like to be able to have nodes of a certain type "lock" after fifteen minutes, so that for the first fifteen minutes after a node of that type has been created its creator can edit that node, but after that fifteen minutes has passed only users with a specific permission can edit that node.

What's the best way to achieve this result?

Comment: Have you already looked at the [Rules module] (https://drupal.org/project/rules)? It has a scheduling functionality so you can invoke a rule restricting access after some time elapsed

Comment: Thanks, @longboardnode! I've ended up going for the custom-coded solution below, as I was struggling to see how I could achieve the result I was after with Rules. Would be interested to hear more details on how I could do that, though!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter
 */
function MY_MODULE_menu_alter(&$items){
  $items['node/%node/edit']['access callback'] = 'MY_MODULE_check_node_access';
}

/**
 * Custom menu access callback for node/%node/edit
 */
function MY_MODULE_check_node_access($op, $node){
  global $user;
  // Note $op and $node are passed in default node_menu access arguments
  // Allow bypass by users with administer nodes permission
  if (($op == 'update') && (!user_access('administer nodes'))) {
    // Allow edit access to node author if within time limit
    if ($user->uid == $node->uid) {
      $limit = variable_get('node_edit_limit', (15 * 60));
      if ((REQUEST_TIME - $node->created) > $limit) {
        drupal_set_message(t('Edit time limit exceeded'));
        return FALSE;
      } else {
        return TRUE;
      }
    }
  }
  // Fallback to regular node_access checks
  return node_access($op, $node);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Module [edit_limit](https://www.drupal.org/project/edit_limit) available for drupal 7 version since 2013-May-28 , just few days before David's answer. May be he was not aware of it that time.
Just few lines from modules page which is specific for OP's requirement.

> Node edit time limit
>
> Nodes can be limited to a given time frame. When this is used, nodes
>   can only be edited within the time limit set by the site
>   administrator, starting when the node is initially saved. This can be
>   limited to a subset of content types.